# PDF Annotation containing Unicode characters(spanning two bytes) are not showing in firefox but working fine in chrome

Tags: pdf, annotations

Setting unicode characters in the Annotation appearance stream using arial unicode is showing up the characters correctly in chrome but not in firefox. Any Idea on this? The annotation appearance stream is as below. For example, to show a tick symbol.

```
 BT /F3 34 Tf 1.0 0.0 0.0 rg 107.44528 635.27405 Td [

  <FEFF27132713>

 ] TJ ET
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your content stream is invalid.

If I understand you correctly, you want to control the encoding of a string parameter of a text showing instruction in a PDF content stream by prefixing it with a Unicode BOM. This does not work:

> A string operand of a text-showing operator shall be interpreted as a sequence of character codes identifying the glyphs to be painted.
>
> With a simple font, each byte of the string shall be treated as a separate character code. The character code shall then be looked up in the font’s encoding to select the glyph, as described in 9.6.5, "Character encoding".
>
> With a composite font (PDF 1.2), multiple-byte codes may be used to select glyphs. In this instance, one or more consecutive bytes of the string shall be treated as a single character code. The code lengths and the mappings from codes to glyphs are defined in a data structure called a CMap, described in 9.7, "Composite fonts".

*(ISO 32000-2, section 9.4.3 "Text-showing operators")*

In case of your example, therefore, that **F3** font

- either is a simple font with some single-byte encoding and your `<FEFF27132713>` string contains 6 separate character codes, each of them representing a glyph by itself if any,
- or is a composite font possibly with a multi-byte encoding and your `<FEFF27132713>` string contains up to 6 separate character codes, each of them representing a glyph by itself if any.

In either case the interpretation of your string depends on a fixed encoding defined by the font object in question, you cannot manipulate it by some BOM prefix.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Here in the example, F3 is the font reference created for arial unicode.  I want to write the appearance stream of the annotation (PDAppearanceStream)  BT Td (text) Tj ET .  Here the text string gets displayed well for a normal text (each character one byte). But for character which are represented as two bytes, text gets translated to  (?z?z) in the PDAppearance stream. And the text annotation displays well in chrome. But the same pdf with annotation when viewed in adobe/firefox shows only the ZZ.

Comment: *"F3 is the font reference created for arial unicode"* - How is it created? As what kind of PDF font object? Using which encoding? That it *"displays well in chrome"* may actually be a Chrome bug because your approach in general will result in an invalid file or at least one not displaying the characters you want.

Comment: I have used PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(new file("C:/arialuni.ttf") to load fonts and have used PDPageContentStream.setFont(font). I am trying to set the appearance stream for an annotation in this pdf page using the F3 font reference created. I could see the font embedded when opened the file in adobe. Its only the annotation text showing different in firefox and adobe. In chrome and Edge it shows the characters perfectly. For example, Annotation text "hello" gets displayed as KHOOR in firefox and adobe. But displays as hello in chrome and edge. Am suspecting it is to do with the encoding.

Comment: *"I have used ..."* - You might want to clarify which library and language you use. At first glance it looks like a PDFBox 2.x for Java but I'm not really sure. So please clarify. Even if I'm right, please indicate which PDFBox version exactly you use, in particular whether it's a current 2.0.20 or 2.0.21 or whether it's older. That being said, my opinion still is that you most likely are creating something invalid and PDF viewers try to repair that, some as you expected, some differently.

Comment: Its pretty old pdfbox 0.7.3 version and java. Yeah probably the way am representing the text content in appearance stream is wrong. Changing my question to a more straightforward question. If i have to display "hello" using unicode and using a font reference , Given that universal Codepoint for hello is (104 101 108 108 111). how do we specify the appearance stream in the below format. BT /F3 34 Tf 1.0 0.0 0.0 rg 107.44528 635.27405 Td () Tj ET Q

Comment: the font reference here is pointing to Arial unicode.

Comment: The name of *Arial Unicode* does not imply that in using it you have to use Unicode encoding, it merely means that it contains glyphs for most of the characters from the Unicode *Plane 0* aka *Basic Multilingual Plane* (BMP). The encoding used for handling that font usually is not UCS-2.

Comment: I have no idea how PDFBox 0.7.3 used to encode composite fonts, so I cannot really help there. I merely can say that I would be really surprised if it used UCS-2 / UTF-16 as encoding.

Comment: I have tried using the same approach as showText. Below code works consistently. PDPageContentStream content = (initialised correctly);